# How to switch off HDMI

Tags: adb, shell, hdmi

I have an android box with a HDMI port. Im connecting it to a projector. To the same projector Im also connecting a PC via VGA cable. Now I want to give my box a command to switch off the HDMI port, so that I can see the image of my PC.

Is there some shell command way to do this? Via ADB? Or any other suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the Android HDMI port in Settings. It is likely either:

- Settings -> HDMI -> Off, or
- Settings -> Display -> HDMI -> Off